# Adding Like/Twitter/Share Buttons to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, twitter, interface-builder, facebook-like

Trying to understand how to add the like/twitter/share buttons to my Facebook Page...been trying to figure this out for days.  Using addit code for my website outside of facebook, but for facebook...i am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have "addit" code working on an external website, what you need to do is create a facebook page tab application.

Page Tab is a special app that goes onto your Facebook page and displays content from another webserver inside of an iframe.

See this tutorial on how to do this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Happy coding!